# Error when trying to merge two UIImages into an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to merge a couple photos (UIImages) into a Image View. I'm using this method:

```
- (UIImage *) addImageToImage:(UIImage *)img withImage2:(UIImage *)img2{

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(finalPhoto.image.size.width, finalPhoto.image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint pointImg1 = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [img drawAtPoint:pointImg1];

    CGPoint pointImg2 = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [img2 drawAtPoint: pointImg2];

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that it cant make the merge because it doesn't have the corrects points (I guess...) Here is the log:

```
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20  <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20  <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20  <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20  <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20  <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Jan 17 09:35:20 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

This problems happens on iOS 6 and iOS 7. Is there a posible solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
- (UIImage *) addImageToImage:(UIImage *)img withImage2:(UIImage *)img2{
    //merge two images for this code

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(512,512); // Set your bottom image size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];///1st image set frame

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [img2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(165,332,165,120) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];//2nd image set frame with alpha value

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage; //return UIImage
}
```

Comment: what is `NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];` ?  I am not using images from files, I'm using 2 `@property (nonatomic) UIImage * firstPhotoImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage * secondPhotoImage;`taken from the camera.

Comment: NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"]; this is for save merge image in your document directory file of your application

Comment: @Vergmort Is it works for you? or Are you facing any problem?

Comment: it's working fine. Just one quick question. Before I merge them, can I positionate them on different positions? (the img1 on the left and the image 2 on the right, because I crop them in the middle when taking the photo, then I merge them)

Comment: @Vergmort you can set its position or frame by changing value of both images using drawInRect:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

Comment: It works perfect on portrait images. One more question. If both images are on landscape instead of portrait, it is there a way to set the merge to make them look good and large? (right now it put them on portrait and I want them to be Landscape)

Comment: i think for that your device orientation should be landscape

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your images are nil pointers, so the rectangle you're using to create your context is empty. Check the value of size before you create your context:

```
NSLog(@"Size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```